# Moderator Pro Tempore Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderators

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed.

[image: Ansari]
[image: goldPseudo]
[image: Bleeding Fingers]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections once your site has graduated.**

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: Congrats you guys! I hope you take this appointment seriously and are ready to work :-)

Comment: @Aarthi what happened to Ashes999? was he inactive?

Comment: @AlUmmat I stepped down by choice.

Comment: @ashes999 okay .

Comment: @Bleeding fingers, Woah, Congrats man :-)

Answer (score 6):

**Congrats to ashes999, Ansari, and goldPseudo!**

Everybody who was nominated would've made a great mod, so I'm sure this was a tough decision. That said, the 3 who were picked, in my opinion, are great choices. They have shown leadership and responsibility throughout the site already, and are still growing.

Congrats again!

Answer (score 1):

Since some of you are already asking, I chose to step down from being a moderator. In my place, Aarthi (in consultation with the other two mods) sought out a replacement moderator -- yasar11732.

I'm still hanging around here and there, but I'm not invested in the site like I used to be.